# NullPointerException for Springboot @Autowired component in interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I have a component that's the main job is to return a Jedis instance, and it looks like the following:

```java
@Component
public class JedisConfig {

    private Jedis jedis;

    public JedisConfig() {
        jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 6379);
    }

    public Jedis getJedis() {return jedis;}
}
```

I then use the Jedis instance to do some stuff in my interceptor's preHandler:

```java
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private JedisConfig jc;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Jedis jedis = jc.getJedis();
        
        // do some other stuff with jedis below
    }
}
```

But I get a NullPointerException when calling `jc.getJedis()` and I don't understand why it's happening.

On a related note, I did pretty much the exact same thing in a unit test and it runs fine:

```java
@Autowired
private JedisConfig jc;

@Test
public void testJedis(){
    Jedis jedis = jc.getJedis();

    jedis.set("user", "role");
    assertThat(jedis.get("user"),is("role"));
}
```

Here's How I added the interceptor to the registry:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor())
                .addPathPatterns("/user/roleChange");
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you use the `AuthInterceptor`?

Comment: Is `AuthInterceptor` in the Spring context? There is no annotation on the class here so we would need to know how it is created

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis, I edited my question. Basically I just added the interceptor to a registry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AuthInterceptor` is not a Spring bean, and the `JedisConfig` is not autowired and is null. As long as the interceptor is used in the @Configuration class, you can perform autowiring there and encapsulating the `JedisConfig` interceptor.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor // either use Lombok or write the constructor by yourself
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private final JedisConfig jc;
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JedisConfig jc;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor(jc))
                .addPathPatterns("/user/roleChange");
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can treat the `AuthInterceptor` as a component and autowire it in the `WebConfig` class:

```java
@Component
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private JedisConfig jc;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Jedis jedis = jc.getJedis();
        
        ...
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowire
    private AuthInterceptor authInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/user/roleChange");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I fixed it by making Authinterceptor a bean. Btw, what's the difference between `@Component` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`? I just did `@Component` and it seems to be working.

Comment: `@RequiredArgsConstructor` is just a Lombok thing to generate a constructor with all required fields to be initialized.